# Perl RegEx non-capturing group with alternative capturing within the group

Tags: regex, perl, regex-group

I'm trying to parse out some mail logs that have the three following possible formats for the relay.

```
Oct 24 03:49:10 mxout/mxout/1.1.1.1 sendmail[4642]: x9NA4Wbp011336: to=<email@company.com>, delay=1+00:44:37, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=459, relay=mail-company.com. [0.0.0.0], tls=no, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by mail-company.com
Oct 24 03:49:10 mxout/mxout/1.1.1.1 sendmail[4642]: x9NA4Wbp011336: to=<email@company.com>, delay=1+00:44:37, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=459, relay=[0.0.0.0], tls=no, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by mail-company.com
Oct 24 03:49:10 mxout/mxout/1.1.1.1 sendmail[4642]: x9NA4Wbp011336: to=<email@company.com>, delay=1+00:44:37, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=459, relay=mail-company.com., tls=no, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by mail-company.com
```

With the this code:

```
my $topat    = '^(\w{3})\s{1,2}(\d{1,2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).+ sendmail\[\d.+\]: (\w+): to=<(\S+)>(?:,|, \[more\],) delay.+, relay=(?:(?:\S+ )?\[(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\]|(\S+)\.), .+, stat=(.+)';

foreach my $line(@i) {
  if($line =~ /$topat/){
    my ($month, $day, $time, $id, $addy, $relay, $stat) = ($line =~ m/$topat/);
     print $line;
     print "$addy $relay $stat\n";
  }
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
Oct 24 03:49:10 mxout/mxout/1.1.1.1 sendmail[4642]: x9NA4Wbp011336: to=<email@company.com>, delay=1+00:44:37, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=459, relay=mail-company.com. [0.0.0.0], tls=no, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by mail-company.com
Use of uninitialized value $stat in concatenation (.) or string at ./reg_test line 26.
email@company.com 0.0.0.0 

Oct 24 03:49:10 mxout/mxout/1.1.1.1 sendmail[4642]: x9NA4Wbp011336: to=<email@company.com>, delay=1+00:44:37, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=459, relay=[0.0.0.0], tls=no, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by mail-company.com
Use of uninitialized value $stat in concatenation (.) or string at ./reg_test line 26.
email@company.com 0.0.0.0 

Oct 24 03:49:10 mxout/mxout/1.1.1.1 sendmail[4642]: x9NA4Wbp011336: to=<email@company.com>, delay=1+00:44:37, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=459, relay=mail-company.com., tls=no, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by mail-company.com
Use of uninitialized value $relay in concatenation (.) or string at ./reg_test line 26.
email@company.com  mail-company.com
```

In the first two cases it properly grabs the address and relay but not the stat.  And in the third it grabs the address and relay but it thinks that $relay is blank and the $stat is the relay.

I've tried a number of different configurations and groups and I can't seem to find the right solution. any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the first line, the `stat` (last group) matches `Deferred: Connection reset by mail-company.com`, isn't it expected? I can't see any specific issues with the third line either, see [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SOpL99/2)

Comment: It does match correctly in the tester, but when I try printing it out with the above code, or if I try printing "$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7\n" I come out with the same errors and problems as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two alternatives in the `relay` field:

```
relay=(?:(?:\S+ )?\[(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\]|(\S+)\.)
                    ^    ----      $6         ----     ^  | ^$7^
```

If it doesn't follow the first pattern but matches the second one, the relay ends up in `$7` and `$stat`. `$stat` is never populated correctly as it needs $8, not $7.

You can use the branch reset pattern that uses the same capture number for all alternatives:

```
(?|(?:\S+ )?\[(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\]|(\S+)\.)
  ^
```

Or, use the original regex and populate two variables:

```
    my ($month, $day, $time, $id, $addy, $relay, $relay_alt, $stat) = $line =~ m/$topat/;
    $relay //= $relay_alt;
```

Comment: Awesome, changing : to | worked perfectly.  Thank you.